# AWS EC2 auto scaling, possible to scale down to zero?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-auto-scaling

I'm running an inferencing endpoint, and would like to have EC2 autoscaling scale down to 0 if there's no connections for, say, 15 minutes. Then I'd like to have it so any time there's more than five connections average per instance, it scales up. Is that possible? Or, is there a better way to handle this? Inferencing takes 2 seconds minimum, 9 seconds maximum, and I don't want people to wait long so I figure five connections is a good threshold for scaling up. However, I tried setting that threshold and putting a minimum of 0 instances, and it never scales up. I can't see why, but I'm assuming it's because it's never getting to five connections which would cause it scale from 0 to 1. So, I need it to scale from 0 to 1 if there's *any* connections at all.

Comment: Scaling takes long time, several minutes. So those first connection will always be lost and not handled.